# How to change VS2015 to run this code after new OS install?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, uwp

I had to reinstall my operating system this week and my code which was running before doesn't run anymore in Visual Studio 2015. (The code is unchanged since then)

When I build and deploy the code I have the following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       DEP3321 : To deploy this application, your deployment target should be running Windows Universal Runtime version 10.0.10586.0 or higher. You currently are running version 10.0.10240.17443. Please update your OS, or change your deployment target to a device with the appropriate version.  HistAppV1
```

After searching on the Google, [this](https://winplatform.wordpress.com/2015/07/28/error-dep3321-cant-deploy-to-windows-10-mobile/) article helped in some sense, so when I unload the project and change the lines from

```
  <DefaultLanguage>en-US</DefaultLanguage>
    <TargetPlatformIdentifier>UAP</TargetPlatformIdentifier>
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.14393.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10586.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
    <MinimumVisualStudioVersion>14</MinimumVisualStudioVersion>
```

When I change it to

```
<TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.10240.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
```

I can successfully build and deploy my application, but it crashes at the splash screen with this error.

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
```

Where I also get an exception which is

```
GattServices    error CS0103: The name 'GattServices' does not exist in the current context
```

I haven't found any clear indication about from which version GattServices are included, but I assume that the change of versioning causes the trouble. How do I solve this problem? Or how can I keep my version, or update my VS to have the appropriate version?

I'm using Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition as in my previous computer install. As I mentioned the OS is a fresh reinstall, with fresh installs of Visual Studio, so I don't really now what is going wrong now.

UPDATE: The latest version is installed and I did a full reinstall of VS2015 with all the packages and still the same error.
[image]

Also, I checked the installed programmes, and everything seems to be there:
[image]

Comment: The windows version you installed is the old one, you will need to update it either via windows update or by using the media creation tool from Microsoft. Gatt services api were not available in the first release and that is why the appi is crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have installed the first release of Windows 10 (version 1507, see [the version history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_10_version_history)). Your code requires version 1511 (November 2015 update). I don't think it makes sense to modify your application to support such an old version. Windows 10 has practically forced updates to later versions so I would not expect any significant number of version 1507 installations in the world. Just install the OS updates on your PC and everything should be working fine again.

Comment: I have installed all the updates that I know of. In Settings -> Update & Security it says: Your device is up to date. Last checked, Today 17:59.

Comment: Try [this tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) from Microsoft (click 'Update now') to force the update. You're on version from July 2015 while the latest version is from March 2017, there even were 2 versions between them.

Comment: Yes, the updater tool was the key here. It took an hour, and the thing is fully working. I don't understand why it said I'm updated, and I don't understand why do I need a separate installer for this, but I guess this is how things at Microsoft work.